# Promise waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, bluebird

I'm an API developer and typically write end-points requiring passing a result from one async call to another async call aka async waterfall.

I usually do this the following way using promises:

```
task1()

.then(result1){

    task2(result1)

    .then(result2){

        task3(result2)

        .then(result3){
            // API response
        })

        .catch(function(err){
            // Task 3 handle err
        })
    })

    .catch(function(err){
        // Task 2 handle err
    })
})

.catch(function(err){
    // Task 1 handle err
})
```

It's obvious that not much has been gained over using callbacks. Instead of "callback hell" I now got "promise hell".

I have looked at [npm bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) but it does not seem that waterfall promises are supported.

Sometimes I would use [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) and wrap tasks that return a promise:

```
const tasks = [

    job1: function(cb){

        task1()

        .then(function(result){
            cb(null, result);
        })

        .catch(function(err){
            cb(err);
        })  
    },

    job2: function(cb, result1){

        task2(result1)

        .then(function(result){
            cb(null, result);
        })

        .catch(function(err){
            cb(err);
        })  
    },

    job3: function(cb, result2){

        task3(result2)

        .then(function(result){
            cb(null, result);
        })

        .catch(function(err){
            cb(err);
        })  
    }
]

async.series(tasks, function(err, results){

    if(err){
        // handle error
    }

    // API callback
});
```

But this is also pretty useless.
And if you're thinking about `Promise.all` that wont work since the result from one tasks is not passed on to the next.

What's the better approach?

Comment: Apart from realseanp's answer (you're using promises wrong) you should know that there is a promisified async.js library - async-q (https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-q) that works directly with promises so you can just return the promise without all that wrapping of callbacks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You've got a promise anti pattern happening. You can return promises from promises to avoid nesting the promises like you've done.

```
promiseOne()
    .then(() => promiseTwo())
    .then(() => promiseThree())
    .then(() => promiseFour());
```

By the way Node supports the built in `Promise` constructor.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do something and then resolve
    resolve();
})
promise().then(() => { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but your solution does not cater for passing results from one async call into another.

Comment: FYI you can just say `promiseOne().then(() => promiseTwo()).then(() => promiseThree()).then(...etc)`.

Comment: Doh... You are absolute correct: I'm doing promises wrong. Got it working :-)

Comment: @ChrisRich  